# How to get process' status from python code?

Tags: python, supervisord

I'd like to operate a process using `supervisorctl` from python code, in order to get the status and make conditional branches like this:

```
import subprocess

status = subprocess.run(["sudo", "supervisorctl", "status", "my_process"])
if status == "STOPPED":
    # Do something
else:
    # Do another thing
```

But this doesn't work. `subprocess.run` returns `CompletedProcess(args=['sudo', 'supervisorctl', 'status', 'my_status'], returncode=0)`. The response doesn't have what the status is.
Is there any way to get the status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `subprocess.check_output()` to get the output returned to you rather than just the return code.

```
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
```

Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

Answer (score 0):

The python [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) documentation describes how `.run()` returns a `CompletedProcess` object.

From there you can retrieve things like status:

```
status = subprocess.run(["sudo", "supervisorctl", "status", "my_process"])
if status.returncode == 0:
    # success
else:
    # something went wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for supervisorctl not to return status 0,
So it's better to use subprocess.run, but add the capture_output parameter to capture the output...
this is my code -

```
output = subprocess.run(['supervisorctl', 'status'], capture_output=True).stdout
# output is: b'webserver                        STOPPED   May 01 03:55 PM\n'
```